# When I shut down Windows, a Blue Screen appears and says "dumping physical memory"

Tags: windows-7, bsod, eclipse, webcam

I'm using Windows 7 32-bit. I'm running Eclipse, and I guess it's because of that.

I'm handling a Webcam with Java code. When I need to force Eclipse to close, next time I shut down my PC, a Blue Screen appears. It says that it's "dumping physical memory" and then it restarts the PC.

Comment: When i need to force eclipse to close only after then when i shutdown my pc then following message is shown and windows restart

Answer (score 1):

You can  use [bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) from nirsoft , with the bugcheck + driver context menu option to look for solutions. In this particular case, this seems like a good option, since its probably some unusual combination of driver and code thats causing it and it gives very detailed information about the crash after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

This blue screen is known as the Blue Screen of Death (or BSoD).  It indicates that something has caused your computer to crash.  My guess would be that force closing Eclipse either leaves something running that Windows cannot close properly when it tries to shut down, or it leaves an entry somewhere telling Windows to close a process or dump some memory that is no longer in use.  As long as the computer continues to be running fine, it is not something that you should be overly worried about, though you should avoid force closing Eclipse and always exit programs properly.

Answer (score 0):

The BSOD will provide you with an error code also. Try Googling the error code to give you a better idea of what might be wrong.